# gitlab: `changes` to files does not re-run if a previous stage failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Imagine a simple .gitlab-ci.yml file with the following

```
stages:
  - test
  - build

test_job:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
  script:
    - exit 1

build_job:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      changes:
        - web-app/**/*
  script:
    - echo "Building..."
```

The first time this pipeline is run, you will see both jobs, however the build_job will not be run because the test_job failed (exit 1).

Correcting the exit 1 (to exit 0, for example) and re-running, you will now only see the test_job because to gitlab, the web-app files havent changed, yet they havent successfully run previously.

So how do you ensure the build_job is run to success??

Comment: build_job isn't running because in your second commit where you change `exit 1` to `exit 0`, the web-app files aren't changing (only the ci file is). Your best bet would be to remove the changes on the build_job.

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario you described, your second commit contains only 1 change to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, therefore your `changes:` rule correctly causes the `build_job` to be excluded from the pipeline as you have configured the pipeline.

For branch pipelines, GitLab will not consider previous commits when evaluating the `changes:` rules.

However, with pipelines for merge requests, [all changes in the merge request are tested](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#use-onlychanges-with-pipelines-for-merge-requests). Which sounds like the behavior you are expecting.

If your goal is for efficient pipelines tracking your features branches, your best course(s) of action might be something like this:

1. Always run the build job on branch pipelines
2. Only apply the `changes:` rule for pipelines for merge requests
3. Optionally, exclude branch pipelines when an MR is open
4. Optionally, adopt a workflow whereby which you open (draft) merge requests when creating your feature branches

An optimized CI configuration that does not skip build job on branches may look like this:

```yaml
build_job:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:  # in the case of merge requests, we can be more efficient
        - web-app/**/*
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never  # skip branch pipelines when MR pipelines exist
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' # but in branch pipelines, build every time
```

Comment: That has some potential, thank you! I didnt realise that about MR's. Will have a play now.  The last bit of building every time in a branch though wont work as there are 100+ lambdas linted, audited and built, so some sort of realisation is needed.  But I like point 4 as a "solution".

Comment: Tried it... won't work. There are 100+ lambdas, so I dont want to build them on every push. However, I need them all built to deploy the MR environment. Using on_change for just merge_requests only builds the lambdas different from the default branch...  may have just used myself as a duck.. got an idea!